# Remote access via website subdomain. How?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, remote

I have 10 Raspberry Pis located at different cities, and I want to **remotely and securely** access them from the office, control them, update the contents, etc.

As I've searched so far, there are several ways to do so like port forwarding, static IP, etc.

Now I want to know whether it's possible to use my domain/host to do so. I have a domain say www.mydomain.com with a US linux host, and I can create as many subdomains as I like on it.

Is it possible to create subdomains like ***rpi01.mydomain.com***, and use these subdomains to remotely and securely access RPis from anywhere in the world !?

And if yes, how can I do this !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Yes to the DNS implementation of "subdomains", yes to remote access being possible, and "take a deep breath first" on should you do it.

You can easily setup an additional host entry (what you referred to as a subdomain) on your DNS provider for each of your remote Pi units.  The exact "how" is different for each different DNS provider, but the essence is that you want to make a new Host or A Record entry to associate "rpi01" with that device's IP address.

This brings up a second, mostly untouched, portion to your question.  You need to know the Pi's public internet address, and it either needs to be unchanging or something you can get an update from (to update the DNS record).  Static IP addresses are the easiest way, but they come at a [normally small] cost.  Other methods include using a dynamic DNS updating service/client (which can either feed or replace the DNS entry above. These too have a cost, one popular site I just checked has 30 host entries at $40/yr)

Next is how do you remote in.  This takes in the fact that you will need to make firewall changes, and most likely static PAT/NAT assignment (port forwarding), so that your internet connected IP can accept the traffic and send it to the internal Pi device.  You'll need to know the ports required for your preferred connection types (VNC, SSH, something else).  The instructions here depend on your routers & firewalls, but this is a fairly common thing to do so I'd imagine that a quick Google search would yield lots of well done instructions.

The final part is "take a deep breath" and consider what you want to do.  The fact that you're asking this means you aren't very familiar with the process.  I won't knock trying something new, that's how we all got here in the 1st place.  But you are talking about putting a computer that lives inside your network directly onto the badlands of the internet, and purposefully leaving the gate wide open for access; that isn't normally a good idea.  You should really make sure your Pi devices are properly hardened before exposing them directly to the internet (passwords changed, unnecessary services disabled, lockout policies in place, etc) Basically, make sure no one but you can ever log into these guys.  Because there are good guys that can see a scan showing a Pi that's internet connected who will try to login with the default username/pass.  Bad guys actually hunt for them (Pi units make great BotNet slaves) and do bad things to your Pi, your network, and occasionally you [via the Pi].  So **BE VERY CAREFUL** when you even dream of connecting a computer (including a Pi) directly to the internet with the intent of making it accessible from the wild.

Comment: Thanks @Ruscal for your comprehensive answer. I do really appreciate your time. So, if I want to access my Pi this way, I need port forwarding or static IP. I just though that this method of assigning a subdomain is actualy an alternative to them!! In this case, I'll just use static IP or port forwarding alone. Have I understood you correct !?

Comment: You will need either port forwarding or some kind of tunneling so that you can get to the Pi through the firewall(s).  The most common method is port forwarding.  You will also need to know the IP address of each Pi, this will require either a dynamic DNS updater, or static IPs.  The most common approach is getting a static IP for each router, and then forwarding a port from the static internet IP to the internal Pi address.     If you already have a domain name being served in DNS, then adding A Record entries for those static IPs is free (and I recommend it as you don't have to remember IPs)

Comment: But, directly to your point, DNS entries are just a way to make things easier; they don't provide remote access all by themselves.  The DNS entry means you can type rpi-01.mydomain.tld instead of remembering 12.127.16.67 (an ATT DNS in the US, fwiw).  Remembering a name pattern (rpi-01, rpi-02, rpi-london, rpi-paris, etc) is easier than remembering IP addresses.  Also, if you ever change ISPs or IP addresses, you can just update the DNS records and everything else keeps working, no going around changing tons of IP settings

Comment: Thanks @Ruscal for your helpful comments. Just one more questions regardin security: If I use static IP + port forwarding (without using subdomains at all), is this still unsecure !?

Comment: It isn't inherently secure.  You can make it more secure by hardening your Pi: turn off all the services you don't need, change the default "pi" user password (or disable it entirely), lock down the ability to sudo, etc.  Remember that if you open VNC or SSH up to the internet, that means ANYONE on the ENTIRE INTERNET has the ability to attempt to connect.  And, this being the internet, people will try just because they can.  If someone else does get into the Pi, then they are on your internal network just like they walked in and plugged in...  Just a big *be careful* is all

Comment: Thanks again @Ruscal for your helpful comment. Is there any other method to remotely access RPi without opening to the internet? somethings that is private between my office and the RPis only !?

Comment: That takes you back into the realm of tunneling connections.  VPNs are common for this task, and something the RPi can handle, but you'd need to setup a terminator in your office to host the connection.  Another method that I just found (and may install on my RPi tonight to test) is using a meet-in-the-middle style connection client like TeamViewer.  https://pages.teamviewer.com/published/raspberrypi/  I've used them for connections to Win and *nix computers before.  Then you have to trust them and their security, but you aren't opening direct holes to the internet et large.

Comment: Thanks again @Ruscal for your helpful comment. As I searched, VPN for RPi is also common. See https://github.com/pivpn/pivpn and https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-a-home-vpn-using-your-raspberry-pi/ for more details.

Comment: @Omid1989 Do note that those locations talk about turning your RPi into a VPN server (a gateway to let external users into your network).  What you're looking for is a VPN server at your office that the remote RPi units will connect into.  Slightly different than the linked articles (unless you're talking about installing an RPi at the office to use as the VPN server)

Comment: Yes @Ruscal, that's right. I need a VPN server at the office, and hence I have to configure RPis as VPN clients.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier way to accomplish what you want is to establish a VPN infrastructure - have a VPN server at your office that the Pis will connect to automatically.  Then, there's only one public IP, and you're exposing a service that's designed to interact with the public internet and be secure.  You can assign each Pi a unique internal ip/DNS name at that point.

Comment: Thanks @dsolimano for your answer. You mean If I establish a VPN at the office, my RPis in different cities can connect to VPN (over internet ?), and only I can connect to them 100% secure; right !? So, how can I do this !?

Comment: That's correct yes.  Setting up a secure VPN infrastructure might be a bit of a long topic for a stack overflow post, but most offices already have one you can tap into.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. The specifics would depend on how your RPis are connected.

If they're using some static access you might be able to set them up with static IPs. Otherwise you will need to find a way to dynamically update the IPs of the domains. Commercial providers such as DynDNS usually use an agent for this that is read to go but it should be rather easy to build one your own. An important part in this is the propagation time of DNS changes as it might be rather long.